# Aborting multiple-step promise chains with custom error handlers

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm writing a multi-step async sequence that involves different possible errors at each step. I want to abort the whole sequence if an error occurs.

I am trying to express this as a linear sequence using `Promise.then()` and `Promise.catch()`. Here is the pseudocode:

```
step1()
.catch(errorAtStep1 => handlerErrorAtStep1)
.then(resultOfStep1 => step2(resultOfStep1))
.catch(errorAtStep2 => handlerErrorAtStep2)
.then(resultOfStep2 => step3(resultOfStep2))
...
```

I understand that I need to throw *something* in each error handler to avoid getting back into the `then(result)` parts. When I throw, though, the execution ends up in the next `catch(error)` block, which was expecting an error that's related to its corresponding step, not that other thing that I threw.

My question is: what are clean ways to handle this, that would minimize distraction when reading the code?

I came up with this class:

```
class AbortChainError extends Error {
  static chain(handler) {
    return function(error) {
      if (error instanceof AbortChainError) throw error
      handler(error)
      throw new AbortChainError()
    }
  }
}
```

that allows the `catch()` blocks to be written as:

```
.catch(AbortChainError.chain(errorAtStep2 => handlerErrorAtStep2))
```

with the additional need to write a final, empty `catch()` block at the end of the sequence.

Can we do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this into an async function, I'd have the error handlers return nothing, and then you can do each step one-by-one and see if the result exists or not - if it doesn't, there was an error, and you can return.

```
const doStuff = async () => {
  const r1 = await step1().catch(handlerErrorAtStep1);
  if (!r1) return;
  const r2 = await step2(r1).catch(handlerErrorAtStep2);
  if (!r2) return;
  // etc
```

It's not the *most* DRY, but I think it's the easiest to understand.

Comment: I hadn't thought of `catch`ing with `await`... can I throw from inside the error handler into a regular `try .. catch` that encloses the whole sequence? That would remove the need for all those ugly `if (!result)` conditions.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option. Personally, I'd prefer `if`s to re-throwing, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, that works great and saved me a few lines. I kept the `AbortChainError` class to hide the re-throwing, at the expense of slightly higher cognitive load.